# Excel perform specific validation on cells

Tags: excel, validation

I'm looking to try and do two separate types of validation.

1. Is it possible to configure validation on a cell to check the first character in that cell and it must be a letter ?

Eg. Anything starting with A-Z case insensitive is fine.

2. Is is possible to set a cell so it can only contain a number ?

I've got the number check working using `=ISNUMBER(J1)` that seems to only allow numbers.

I'm trying to check the first character and have tried:
`=ISTEXT(LEFT(B10,1))` but that doesn't seem to do what I was hoping..

Thanks

Comment: The answer to both questions is "yes".  Please [edit] the post to show what you have tried so we know where to start helping you.

Comment: @ScottCraner original post updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if the whole cell is text is easy with just a simple formula, but if you want to check for only the first letter, then it's more involved.

To ensure that the first character is NOT a number, you can use the custom validation formula

```
=NOT(ISNUMBER(SUM(LEFT(A1,1),0)))
```

That will still allow special characters llike `$` or `&` etc. as the first character. If you only want to allow a-z and A-Z as the first letter, then use

```
=AND(CODE(LEFT(A1,1))>=56,CODE(LEFT(A1,1))<=122)
```

[image]

To allow only numbers, use the built in validation options for Decimal or Whole Number.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Select one or more cells to validate.
- Open the Data Validation dialog box.
- For this, click the Data Validation button on the Data tab, in the Data Tools group or press
  the key sequence Alt > D > L (each key is to be pressed separately).
- On the Settings tab of the Data Validation dialog window, select Custom in the Allow box, and enter your data validation formula in
  the Formula box.
- Click OK.

For text only in a cell build a custom rule with the ISTEXT function, for example:

=ISTEXT(D2)

Custom rule for numbers only in a cell using ISNUMBER.

=ISNUMBER(D2)

Reference: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/08/17/use-data-validation-excel-custom-rules-formulas/

Comment: That happily allows `123abc` as valid text. The questions states that the first character should be a letter.

Comment: Thanks for this. but I want to check if the first character is a letter.